# Unity-particle effect on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript, particle-system

This is my first time using Unity and I'm having trouble making the particles come out of pick up items. The coding is in C#. Long story short the particles systems need to start working when a player collides with the pick up items. Ever time I run the project or code it doesn't work What am I doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Particles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem part;
    public ParticleCollisionEvent[] collisionEvents;
    void Start()
    {
        part = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        collisionEvents = new ParticleCollisionEvent[16];
    }
    void OnParticleCollision(Particles other)
    {
        int safeLength = part.GetSafeCollisionEventSize();
        if (collisionEvents.Length < safeLength)
            collisionEvents = new ParticleCollisionEvent[safeLength];

        int numCollisionEvents = part.GetCollisionEvents(other, collisionEvents);
        Rigidbody rb = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < numCollisionEvents)
        {
            if (rb)
            {
                Vector3 pos = collisionEvents[i].intersection;
                Vector3 force = collisionEvents[i].velocity * 10;
                rb.AddForce(force);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/explosions?playlist=17147. You want to instantiate your particles in OnTriggerEnter of your "Pick Up" game object

Comment: What LibertyLockef said. It is best to instantiate a empty gameobject that holds the particle system when the item collides with the player. Or if it needs to follow the item, you can make the empty gameobject a child of the item, inactivate it, then activate it when the item collides with the player.